# dynamic page content using $_GET['value'] as pointer

Tags: php, mysql

I created a dynamic menu. for each menu item I have set

```
"<li>" . "<a href=\"content.php?page=" . urlencode($pages["menu"]) . "\">" . $pages["menu"] . "</a>" . "</li>"
```

my next plan was to grab that $_GET['page'] and put it in a variable

```
if (isset($_GET['page'])) {
      $page_id = $_GET['page'];
    }
```

then create another query that says

```
$query = "SELECT * ";
  $query .= "FROM ccms.pages ";
  $query .= "WHERE p.menu =" . $page_id;
  $query .= " LIMIT 1";
```

and then echo out p.content.

All goes according to plan, except for the last part.

If my approach is totally crooked, or stupid even, please point me in another direction. If it isn't that bad, why do I not get any result? Not even an error message.

My full code below:

**content.php**

```
<?php
    require_once 'includes/connect.php';
    if (isset($_GET['page'])) {
      $page_id = $_GET['page'];
    }
    require_once("includes/functions.php");
    include("includes/header.php");
?>

    <div id="nav">
        <ul style="font-size:22px;">
            <?php
            $info_set = get_all_info();

            while($information = $info_set->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
            echo "<li>" . "<a href=\"content.php?info=" . urlencode($information["menu"]) .
            "\">" . $information["menu"] . "</a>" . "</li>"; 

            $page_set = get_pages_for_info($information['id']);

            echo "<ul style=\"font-size:16px;\">";

            while($pages = $page_set->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
            echo "<li>" . "<a href=\"content.php?page=" . urlencode($pages["menu"]) .
            "\">" . $pages["menu"] . "</a>" . "</li>"; 
            }
            echo "</ul>";   
            }
            ?>
            </ul>
        </div>

    <div id="content"> 

        <h4><?php get_info_by_id() ?></h4>


        <?php $page = get_page_by_id($Page_id); ?>



    </div> <!--end of main content-->

<?php require("includes/footer.php");?>
```

**functions.php**

```
<?php

function get_all_info(){
    global $db;
    $query = "SELECT * FROM ccms.information ORDER BY position ASC";
    $info_set = $db->prepare($query);                
    $info_set->execute();
    return $info_set;
}


function get_pages_for_info($information_id){
    global $db;
    $query = "SELECT * FROM ccms.pages p where p.information_id = :iid ORDER BY position ASC";
    $page_set = $db->prepare($query);                
    $page_set->bindParam(':iid', $information_id);
    $page_set->execute();
    return $page_set;
} 

function get_info_by_id() {
    if (isset($_GET['info'])) {
      $id = $_GET['info'];
      echo $id;
    }
}

function get_page_by_id($page_id) {
  global $db;
  $query = "SELECT * ";
  $query .= "FROM ccms.pages ";
  $query .= "WHERE p.menu =" . $page_id;
  $query .= " LIMIT 1";
  $result_set = $db->prepare($query);
  $result_set->execute();
  if($page = $result_set->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    return $pages['id'];
  } else {
    return NULL;
  }  
}

?>
```

Comment: Add required files on top & call the get_page_by_id() inside if bcz you are passing the page id parameter <?php
    require_once 'includes/connect.php';
    require_once("includes/functions.php");
    if (isset($_GET['page'])) {
      $page_id = $_GET['page'];
      $page = get_page_by_id($Page_id);
    }
     include("includes/header.php");
?>

Comment: Thank you for your response. Unfortunately this throws an error -> Undefined variable: Page_id. For some reason the variable isn not defined yet???

Comment: write in small letters $page_id

Comment: silly mistake, sorry about that. thing is, it still throws the same error: Undefined variable: page_id .

Comment: check error line number... may you did not remove the <?php $page = get_page_by_id($Page_id); ?> at bottom

Comment: that is correct. If removed, it does not throw an error anymore, which leaves me at the beginning, why isn`t there any result given back? Is my function get_page_by_id incorrect? where is the result being echo'd out? I am a bit lost. sorry!

Comment: In `get_page_by_id` you set `$page = $result_set->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)` but then you `return $pages['id'];`. I think that should be `return $page['id'];`

Comment: any other ideas?

Comment: First "echo $page_id" in if condition ... if it returns number then in get_page_by_id() var_dump your result... If your page_id return NULL then do not call  get_page_by_id().... Try to debug  your code..

Comment: You are right. I found my code confusing, more specific the server in, out browser in out cycle was not right. I am restructuring the idea and will post the outcome here when that happened. Thanks!